# How to render MVC 4 view on slickgrid double click via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I am using MVC4 along with slickgrid to display data to the user. I am trying to implement the ability to double click on a slickgrid row and have the page go to another view, but all I am able to get is the HTML returned to the client, but not rendered.

I am doing,

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    $.get(
        "MapSetEdit/Edit/",
        { 'mapSetId': 1 }

        );
});
```

and I have also tried:

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "MapSetEdit/Edit/",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {'mapSetId': 1}
    })
      .fail(function () {
          console.log("Error retreiving map list.");
      });
});
```

All this does is return the html to the browser but never renders it. How do I make a javascript request so that I am able to actually render the view. I think I am missing something obvious here as I am new to javascript and mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You should render the returned HTML with jQuery. For example:

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "MapSetEdit/Edit/",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {'mapSetId': 1}
    })
      .succes(function(data){
          var someemptydiv = $("#myEmptyDiv");
          someemptydiv.html(data);
       })
      .fail(function () {
          console.log("Error retreiving map list.");
      });
});
```

Comment: I would like to render the HTML as new page, not inside a div

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed with:

```
    grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    window.location = '/MapSetEdit/Edit/?mapSetId=1'
});
```